# Apps Script - Sending email through an alias

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-email

I wrote the script below to send a template html email to a list of emails in a sheet through an alias (the alias is already in my gmail account and I have provided access).

```
function sendEmail() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('list');
var n=sheet1.getLastRow();
for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();
 
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('template').evaluate().getContent();
 
var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
Logger.log(aliases);
 
GmailApp.sendEmail({
to: emailAddress,
from: "blabla@gmail.com",
subject: ('Document'),
htmlBody: html,
});
}
}
```

But I am getting the error:

Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for GmailApp.sendEmail.
sendEmail   @ Code.gs:13

Helppp, please!

Comment: This is javascript, and should not be using the java tag. Java is not related to javascript.

Comment: sorry about that.. it was a typo!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked your script and found that the main issue is with the parameter structure used in your `GmailApp.sendEmail()` line. According to this official [sample for sending email via alias](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getaliases) on the GmailApp class article, the parameter structure should be something like this:

> `GmailApp.sendEmail(me, 'From an alias', 'A message from an alias!', {'from': aliases[0]});`

**SOLUTION**

You can test this tweaked script:

***UPDATED***

```
function sendEmail() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('list');
var n=sheet1.getLastRow();
for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();

var html =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('template').evaluate().getContent();
 
var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
Logger.log(aliases);

GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, 'Document', 'Please see the message.', {
    htmlBody: html,
    name: "Sender Name", //On my testing, it looks "name" (Sender Name) is needed for the alias email to work and for the email to be sent to to recipient successfully
    from: aliases[0]
}); 
}
}
```

Comment: Hey.. thank you for your help... it worked for the alias but the email is displaying the html script instead of the email text. any ideas?

Comment: Reviewed the Class GmailApp article and used a reference from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options. Updated my script, specifically on GmailApp.sendEmail part,  you can test it. I did a test on my end and it worked as it showed the content of the html template.