# Forward email to a forwarding address manually using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to forward emails to a forwarding address, like a [Gmail filter](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en) would, using Apps Script. The transferred email should therefore be an exact copy of the original one: same subject, body and from address (that's the tricky one).

My current code is a workaround and uses the 'usual' transfer function with some of its advanced parameters:

```js
message.forward(
    'dude@example.com',
    {
        name: message.getFrom(),
        replyTo: message.getFrom(),
        subject: message.getSubject()
    }
)
```

The forwarded email however still appears as being sent from the forwarding address, and not the original sender address. This sometimes even messes up the Gmail threads...

---

[EDIT] 
Aliases (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67838494/apps-script-sending-email-through-an-alias) question) are not the solution here since forwarding addresses can be a completely different account, especially in the context of a Google Workspace.

Comment: The problem is that you have to create another alias for every email from address you wish to use.  It looks like you can create and verify aliases with Google API https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/verify

Comment: Aliases are not the same as forwarding addresses, and the former are not the solution to my problem, sadly (see edit).

Comment: I reopened the questioin